# C# WPF Image on Button cut off

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I Created a style for my Buttons:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="Border.Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/myTool.GUI;component/Resources/Button not clicked.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Border.Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/myTool.GUI;component/Resources/Button clicked.png"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

if i use know a Button in my Windows it looks good in the Designer:
[image: Button in Designer]

But if i start my Application it looks like this:
[image: Button in Live Mode]

Why is the left and right side cut off?

Original Image:
[image]

Comment: My guess is about the poor resolution of the source image (image brush). What is the size of it?

Comment: Dimensions: 3415x1042 with a Bit depth from 32

Comment: I tried with a small 64x64 PNG image, but it looks nice. It scales correctly to 20 px as well to 200px. However, it has no sense using a so large image for a small button. Use a resolution comparable with the size of the button.

Comment: I have now reduced the image to 341x104, but the problem still exists.

Comment: could you post the images somewhere?

Comment: sure it is now in my main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, is about the original image, which is not well-tailored for the desired size (e.g. 20x20px). If I try to resize it using Paint or another app, the result is the same as the WPF rendering.

In particular, I think it's the border too thin. You have a 341px wide image with just 7px thick border. That is a 7 / 341 = 0.0205 ratio.

Now, when you scale down to 20px wide, the border become 20 * 0.0205 = 0.4px. So, less than a single pixel! can't get a decent result that way.

That being said, you could try to improve the result by adjusting the [RenderingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.renderoptions?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) properties. For instance, you could try the following:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="..." 
    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" 
    RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information! What do you think would be the best solution to use the image for 20x20 buttons as well as for 150x20 buttons?

Comment: These two sizes have a very different ratio (W/H), thus I'd make two images respecting each ratio. By the way, since usually the scaling algorithms works well with sizes having power of two or multiple of them, I'd choose a 32x32px for the smaller and 256x32px for the rectangular one. Even better, if you can enlarge a bit the buttons to 24x24px and 180x24px. I think the graphical result should be very good.